# SystemVerilog error 10748

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am using SystemVerilog to handle a 3-dimensional array. My code is as follows.

```
module sub_bytes();


reg [7:0] word_stream_reg [0:1][0:1]= '{'{8'hFF,8'hA4},'{8'h50,8'hC6}};
reg [7:0] test = word_stream_reg[0][1][7:0]; 


endmodule
```

I get this error:

`Error (10748): Verilog HDL error at sub_bytes.v(6): expression in variable declaration assignment to test must be constant`

I spent about 4 hours but could not find the reason for this error. I would be grateful if anyone could assist me in this.

Comment: The value stored in reg is not constant (it can be change), so you can't use it to initialize another reg at time 0.

Comment: @dehrg Thank you. I am just trying to part bits in 1 byte in the array. This is done as a part of the implementation of AES algorithm.

Comment: @Qiu I just cant understand how the stored value is not a constant

Comment: However this works when I do this inside an always block

Answer (score 2):

Even if some tools allow it, it is a very bad programming practice to initialize a static variable with a another static variable. This is refereed to the "*static initialization fiasco*" in many programming languages. Outside of a procedural context, there is no defined ordering of static initializers.

Assigning a constant value to a variable  does not make that variable a constant. It's still a variable as far as the compiler is concerned.

What you probably want to do is use a `parameter` instead of a variable.

```
parameter logic [7:0] word_stream_reg [0:1][0:1]= '{'{8'hFF,8'hA4},'{8'h50,8'hC6}};
```

Note: Since you are using SystemVerilog, use `logic` instead of `reg`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Qui say referencing another variable for initialisation does not work with some simulators.

Why not use:

```
reg  [7:0] word_stream_reg [0:1][0:1]= '{'{8'hFF,8'hA4},'{8'h50,8'hC6}};
wire [7:0] test = word_stream_reg[0][1][7:0];
```